# Remapping "Web/Home", "My Computer" and "Calculator" keys in Windows 8.1?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1

Previously, I had a keyboard that had extra keys for launching the default web browser, mail client, open "My Computer" in explorer,  the calculator, etc. That keyboard was from 2003 and it now finally died (it was a membrane keyboard.) Now I bought a new mechanical keyboard that doesn't have these keys. It only has media keys.

In Linux, I was able to remap all that functionality very, very easily and without any trouble. For example, I've configured win+w to open the default web browser, win+m opens the mail client, win+c the calculator, etc. But for Windows (I'm using 8.1 64-bit), I can't find a way to do the same.

Is there a way to do this other than using shortcuts with control+alt combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be pinning those programs to the taskbar. Then you can press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (this number can be changed, depending on how they're ordered).

Comment: Seems like the only alternative without using third-party tools.